# MongoDB find query returns too many documents

Tags: mongodb, meteor

My find query below returns both documents. I only want it to return the document where a classes object equals all of the criteria instead of just one.

**`Documents`**

```
{name: 'James', classes: { classId: '1', wednesday: true}}
{name: 'Greg', classes: { classId: '1', thursday: true}}
```

**Query**

```
UserProfiles.find({
  $and: [
    { 'classes.classId': 1 },
    { 'classes.wednesday': true },
  ],
});
```

Comment: UserProfiles.find({
    'classes.classId': 1 ,'classes.wednesday': true 
}); just try as above.I haven't tested it.

Comment: still getting the same result with this.

Comment: So I found this old post that explains exactly what I'm trying to do. You're suppose to use `$elemMatch`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914664/mongo-query-on-multiple-fields-of-sub-document

Comment: It's working https://mongoplayground.net/p/hyhm7_hd25x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found here. [Mongo Query On Multiple Fields Of Sub-Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914664/mongo-query-on-multiple-fields-of-sub-document)

FYI:

You're supposed to use `$elemMatch`.

```
UserProfiles.find({
  classes: {
    $elemMatch: {
      classId,
      [weekday]: true,
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB find by default uses '$and' rewrite your query like this...

UserProfiles.find({"classes.classId":'1', "classes. wednesday":true});